# My AVSpeechSynthesizer (text to speech) is talking at a very fast rate and I can't figure out how to slow it down

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

so i have a perfect AVSpeechSynthesizer (text to speech) on swift 2.0 Xcode 7.1.1 but i can't figure out how to make it talk like we do at a normal pace or even slower?
Code:

```
 import UIKit
 import AVKit
 import AVFoundation

 class HomePage: UIViewController {
 let Voice = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 let TilteSpeakingText1 = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Welcome back. The database should still be up for you")
            Voice.speakUtterance(TilteSpeakingText1)
            TilteSpeakingText1.rate = 0.003
            TilteSpeakingText1.pitchMultiplier = 0.60
            TilteSpeakingText1.volume = 0.75
            TilteSpeakingText1.postUtteranceDelay = 0.01
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you on a device or the sim? Does the speaking rate setting in the Settings app have any affect? http://i.imgur.com/BImbqfJ.png

Comment: @MattLong, where is the speech rate setting in Settings? I can' find it.

Comment: General > Accessibility > Speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVSpeechUtterance` has a rate property. Try reducing the rate.

Comment: I'm now at TilteSpeakingText.rate = 0.00003 lol and still fast

Comment: There is something wrong then. I just did a quick test and the default rate of 0.5 seems pretty reasonable. A rate of 0.1 makes the speech sound like the speaker is half-asleep, or drunk.

Comment: Hmm. That was on the sim. When I run on a device with iOS 8.4, I see what you mean. The default rate of 0.5 is a little fast. I just tried 0.01 and that is quite slow. A rate of 0.1 seems quite natural on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Speak the utterance AFTER setting rate, pitch and volume properties:

```
//Voice.speakUtterance(TilteSpeakingText1) <-remove this
            TilteSpeakingText1.rate = 0.003
            TilteSpeakingText1.pitchMultiplier = 0.60
            TilteSpeakingText1.volume = 0.75
            TilteSpeakingText1.postUtteranceDelay = 0.01
Voice.speakUtterance(TilteSpeakingText1)//call here instead
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -:

```
let speechUtterance: AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
speechUtterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate / 2.0
```